# Скрытие блока: как добиться такого эффекта?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Не пойму, как добиться такого эффекта.

При скрытии блока нужно его поднять вверх, но проблема с контентом, который под блоком, его нужно поднимать по мере скрытия самого блока.

Вот пример
[link text](http://jsfiddle.net/webphp/5x0jdvwe/).

Как видно, остается пустое место. Понятно, что можно еще и блок с контентом поднять, а можно ли обойтись без поднятия контента, т.е. можно ли создать такой же эффект совместно с `slideToggle()`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5x0jdvwe/3/ можно попробовать такой вариант, вместо top использовать margin-top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L6mxrh8y/1/

HTML

```
<ul class="block">
    <li><button id="hide">скрыть блок</button></li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
</ul>
<div>этот текст должен следовать в ходе закрытия блока</div>
<button class="reset">nоказать блок (для теста)</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#hide').on('click', function(){
        $('.block').slideUp();  
});

$('.reset').on('click', function(){
    var x = $('.block').slideDown();
});
```

CSS

```
.block {
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"display: none" поможет. (плавности не будет)
или высота блока меняется на 0. тогда и верхний блок подтянется.